# SQL Server 2008 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string with where clause providing multiple values to a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

There are many solutions for the similar type of question but I did not correctly get the solution for this question.

I have a query where I need to retrieve 'presentstatus' column value from a table by providing multiple employee ids in where condition.

This happens for me in SQL-Server 2008

My query is

```
select Present_status 
from EmployeeStatus 
where 
    Employee in ('1','2','3','4','5','6') and 
    convert(datetime,stringdate,103) between convert(datetime,'01/01/2016',103) and convert(datetime,'20/01/2016',103)
```

this gives me the error...

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

But,

```
select Present_status 
from EmployeeStatus 
where 
    Employee in ('1') and 
    convert(datetime,stringdate,103) between convert(datetime,'01/01/2016',103) and convert(datetime,'20/01/2016',103)
```

This works well ...

Comment: Well - you have a value in your `stringdate`data that's not convertable using the 103 format. Find that value and fix it, and your error will go away

Comment: To add to what Allan wrote, this would not be a problem if you would have used the proper data types for your database, and the stringdate column would not be a string representing dates but an actual date or datetime value.

Comment: @ZoharPeled

stringdate is a varchar(10) type and the string will be in the format dd/MM/yyyy.  The result is perfect if I give only one value to 'Employee' i.e I write it as Employee='1' or Employee in ('1)

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a `varchar`. that's my point, it should be `date`, or at least `datetime`. the fact that it's a `varchar` is the source of your current problem (and potentially many more problems).

Comment: Oh !
But I get the results correctly for a 95% similar type of query with two tables.
And the main problem I am getting is because of sending multiple values into Employee column to compare.

Comment: No, my dear. The problem is because, as Allan rightfully wrote, that you have somewhere a value in that stringDate column that can not be converted to a valid date value using the 103 style.

Comment: Thanks, @ZoharPeled

I guess I could get it.
Once I get it, I'll definitely post my answer here.
Thank you all for your valuable time and answers.

Comment: Thanks, @AllanS.Hansen